How to make Automapper deal with not found input properties?
I have two classes: CustomerLocation and UILocation. Both have a property, called Product but in both cases the type of that Products are different.
I'm performing following piece of source code and I get an error message:
try
{
    UiLocation uiLocation = _mapper.Map<UiLocation>(customerLocation);
}
catch (Exception ex1)
{
    _logger.Error($"An exception happened .... Exception message=[{ex1.Message}]");
}

Exception message:
Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
CustomerLocation -> UiLocation
Company.Customer.Server.Domain.CustomerLocation -> Company.Customer.Class.UiLocation

Type Map configuration:
CustomerLocation -> UiLocation
Company.Customer.Server.Domain.CustomerLocation -> Company.Customer.Class.UiLocation

Destination Member:
Product
]

As far as I understand, mapper.Map executes a mapping, which means that all properties of the originating object get copied to the property with the same name. In case the mentioned property's type is different, the same mapping is done over there.
I have this this code working fine, but while performing on a customer system, I'm seeing the mentioned error message. Clearly something is wrong with the mapping of the Product property, but what??? Can anybody point me in a direction?
(In the meantime this is clear: the source Product was not found: in DB, an ID is filled in, but this ID does not correspond with an actual product).
Update after some insights:
I've added the following line (in order to allow empty destinations):
var locationConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AllowNullDestinationValues = true;  // This allows AutoMapper to return null for any destination properties if the source is null
    cfg.CreateMap<CustomerLocation, UiLocation>();
});

However, this has as a consequence that the whole mapping does not work anymore (even when there's nothing wrong with the product).
What other means do I have? (The source is not null but not found: there is an ID, filled in in DB, but there is no number, corresponding with that ID.
What now?

Do you have UnitTests for the mapping? Can you come up with one that produces the error seen? What are the respective types? Are all mappings configured?

You should tell what mapper you use. If its Automapper then check via its AssertConfigurationIsValid method if the mapping configuration is considered valid (thats not perfect but often gives enough hints). And yes at best as part of more complete unit test.

And you should look more closely at the exception you get. Presumably there is more detail then just the message. For example some inner exceptions with more details.

Please provide a minimal, reproducible example. Right now, we don't even know what _mapper is.

@Ralf: that's the point: the problem does not occur on my PC, but it happens at customer premises, where I don't have debugging facilities. Currently I've copied the "Generate Script" of the SQL-Server database in order to have the same database than the customer, hoping to reproduce the problem on my PC, but now I'm having some problems because of the size of the script, which causes OutOfMemoryExceptions. I'm splitting the script into different separated scripts, hoping to avoid the OutOfMemoryException.

@MarkSeemann: _mapper is an AutoMapper as defined in the package packages\AutoMapper.10.1.1\lib\net461\AutoMapper.dll.

I am suspecting a specific value crashing the mapping. Config may be correct, if you get a funky value, it can still blow up in your face at runtime. That's why I always and for every mapping (no matter if Automapper, Mapster, or manual)  write UnitTests where I can define the allowed (and agreed upon) set of values. If the test fails - it's on me. If customer puts in unexpected data, I can prove it's on them. They might still want me to fix it, but at least I can communicate it's not a bug, it's a new feature.

You mention that Product has a different type on each of the classes being mapped. How is the mapping between these different types configured? It may be helpful to see some of the mapping configuration.

You need ex.ToString() for the full error message.

It might be caused by differing assemblies, depending on how your AutoMapper is configured in Program.cs. If you haven't already, try and see if you will get the same error locally but run the app with the same files(release configuration) as the production ones.

You could try sth like this:
var locationConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<CustomerLocation, UiLocation>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Product, opt =>
        {
            opt.PreCondition(src => src.Product != null && src.Product.IsValid()); // Check if the Product is valid
            opt.MapFrom(src => src.Product != null ? MapProduct(src.Product) : null); // Use a custom mapping function or set to null if not found
        });
});

IMapper mapper = locationConfiguration.CreateMapper();

This only maps Product if it’s not null and passes an IsValid() check; otherwise, the mapping for Product is skipped. If Product is valid, it uses a custom MapProduct function to map it; if not, it sets UiLocation.Product to null.

The PreCondition guarantees the product is not null, the null check in the MapFrom is useless. Also, null checks are built-in.

In the meantime I've seen that, next to the Product property, my CustomerLocation also contains a ProductID. The latter is always filled in and the erroneous case happens when that ProductID cannot be found in database. Hence, using a simple if-clause, I have found a way to solve my problem. Nevertheless, you have done the effort of finding an approach (not copying from A.I., like Emmanuel), which has learnt me a lot about mapping configuration (and how to avoid using it :-) ), hence I'll accord you the bounty.

This approach ensures that the Product is only mapped if it exists and is valid, otherwise, it sets the Product property to null
var locationConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<CustomerLocation, UiLocation>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Product, opt =>
        {
            opt.MapFrom(src => src.Product != null && ProductExists(src.Product.Id) ? MapProduct(src.Product) : null);
        });
});

IMapper mapper = locationConfiguration.CreateMapper();



